# How can I convert an int into its corresponding set of bitwise flags without any enum

Tags: c#

Is it possible to get all possible bitwise values form an int without any enum?

The scenario is that I need to retrieve comments from a remote database. The database has a fixed comments table with a MASK field that identifies each comment.

```
1 = "comment one"
2 = "comment two"
4 = "comment three"
8 = "comment four"
.
.
.
etc
```

Then on another table, the selected comment combination is referenced using a bitwise int.  These comments can be added to or changed by at the remote end via a web interface.  My client app needs to just pull back the comments that were selected for a given record so I effectively need to reverse engineer a bitwise flag int into all its possible ints.  As the comments table at the remote end is changeable, i cannot use an enum.

So can anyone tell me, Using c# how do I reverse engineer a bitwise int into its individual ints please?

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Bitwise [and](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx) (`&`) and [or](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx) (`|`) are operations you are looking for. I.e. take bit corresponding to 8:

```
 var commentForFlag = value & 8;
```

Note that enums or named constants may make code more readable like `value & CommentMask.Forth`.

One more thing you may be looking for is bit-shifts [<<](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx):

```
for (var commentIndex = 0; commentIndex < 32; commentIndex)
{
   var isThere = (value & (1 << commentIndex)) != 0;
   Console.WriteLine("Comment {0} is present = {1}", commentIndex, isThere);
}
```

Comment: How would I use them?  Say I had a comments value of 72 in my items table.  How do I get the individual ints form that ?

Comment: @user2026382 - I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for... Can you update your post with approximate code you want to write?

Comment: @user2026382 - maybe you are looking for bit-shifts to produce mask with single bit set at given position (added sample to the answer)?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder am I on to something here

```
    private static IEnumerable<int> GetValues(int maskValue)
    {                        
        int max = 131072;

        for (int i = max; i > 0; i/=2)
        {
            int x = i & maskValue;
            if (x > 0)
            {
                yield return x;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seems to work for all values except 1. Can anyone help ?

Comment: My apologies, it does work for 1, I was inputting wrong value.  OK can we accept this as a solution to my own question ?

Comment: Nice approach for making it more generic.

Answer (score 0):

Use `& or | operators`

Sample for two int values 187 and 32.

```
  10111011  =  187
  00100000  =  32
  AND
  00100000  =  32
```

We could do this as

```
int a = 187, b = 32;
int result = a & b;
```

Comment: Not sure how to use this

Comment: Lets say I lookup my database and see that for record x, the user commentsbitmask value is 512, or it could be 8 or even 6144.  I then need to take this int and reverse engineer it into all its possible values. I then take those values and use them to lookup my fixed comments table above and get a list of comments. Is this making sense ?

Answer (score 0):

As others above have mentioned, you'd use the bit-wise operators (`&` and `|`) for determining the bits set for a given integer value. Below is a sample of how to use them:

```
namespace Playground2014.ConsoleStuff
{
    using System;

    internal static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            const int MaskForCommentOne = 1;
            const int MaskForCommentTwo = 2;
            const int MaskForCommentThree = 4;
            const int MaskForCommentFour = 8;
            const int MaskForCommentFive = 16;
            const int MaskForCommentSix = 32;
            const int MaskForCommentSeven = 64;
            const int MaskForCommentEight = 128;

            int myCommentNumber = 72;
            Console.WriteLine("My input number is: {0}", myCommentNumber);
            if(MaskForCommentOne == (myCommentNumber & MaskForCommentOne))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Comment One");
            }

            if(MaskForCommentTwo == (myCommentNumber & MaskForCommentTwo))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Comment Two");
            }

            if(MaskForCommentThree == (myCommentNumber & MaskForCommentThree))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Comment Three");
            }

            if(MaskForCommentFour == (myCommentNumber & MaskForCommentFour))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Comment Four");
            }

            if(MaskForCommentFive == (myCommentNumber & MaskForCommentFive))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Comment Five");
            }

            if(MaskForCommentSix == (myCommentNumber & MaskForCommentSix))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Comment Six");
            }

            if(MaskForCommentSeven == (myCommentNumber & MaskForCommentSeven))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Comment Seven");
            }

            if(MaskForCommentEight == (myCommentNumber & MaskForCommentEight))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Comment Eight");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output should be the following:

```
My input number is: 72
Comment Four
Comment Seven
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks but Im trying to avoid hardcoding values and multiple if statements. Appreciate your answeer though.